# Работа с эксель файлами через пайтон

Tags: python, excel

Допустим есть эксель файл, в котором третья ячейка(C1) считает сумму первых двух ячеек (A1,B!). Формула задана изначально в третей ячейке (=A1+B1). Значения для первой и второй ячеек мы задаем при помощи кода на пайтон, затем извлекаем при помощи кода итоговое решение формулы т.е. (ячейку С1). Проблема в том, что пока я не открыл эксель и не сохранил его вручную (после манипуляций кодом) значения посчитанные формулой не выводятся ячейка выдает None.
вот код задаёт значения в эксель:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
 
#ввод входящих данных 
fn="Лист2.xlsx" 
wb=load_workbook(fn) 
ws=wb['page3'] 
  
ws['B2']=3333 
ws['B3']=4444 
 
wb.save(fn) 
wb.close()
```

вот код выводит значение заданой ячейки:

```
import openpyxl 
 
wb=openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename="Лист2.xlsx", read_only=True,data_only=True) 
# help(openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook) 
print(wb.sheetnames) 
wb.active=2 
 
sheet=wb.active 
 
print(sheet['B2'].value) 
print(sheet['B3'].value) 
print(sheet['C2'].value) 
print(sheet['C3'].value)
```

По сути параметр data_only=True должен превращать формулу в посчитанное значение но выдаётся None потому что видимо библиотека openpyxl не может не открывая файл экселя самой программой посчитать эту формулу, только когда я вручную сохраняю, он выдает нормальные значения без None.
Как решить данную проблему, уже всё перепробовал.
Может быть есть библиотека в которой можно выполнить расчет формул экселя не открывая его или тому подобное?
(В общем нужно чтобы эксель принимал значения для расчета формулы не открываясь считал их и выводил на консоль)

Comment: Вот здесь много разных вариантов предлагают в ответах: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451973/calculating-excel-sheets-without-opening-them-openpyxl-or-xlwt

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял задачу. Я бы советовал либо сохранить файл сразу после расчётов, а потом сохранить в конце, либо всё считать в программе, а потом один раз записать в конце все данные.
Не уверен, что применение "openpyxl.reader.excel" уместно, потому что заранее известно что и где находится (ячейки и данные).
В экселе либо есть данные в ячейке, даже если это None, либо нет.

Comment: Мне нужен такой способ чтобы не открывая файл Excel сохранить его (при этом чтобы все формулы которые имеются в файле посчитались). На сколько я понял openpyxl не позволяет посчитать формулы не открывая файла, по-этому хотел узнать как иначе можно посчитать формулы в файле экселя не открывая его непосредственно.

Comment: Вообще не открывая не получится. "Кто-то" его всё равно должен открыть, даже если это питон.
А зная формулы расчёта делайте всё питоном, а потом можно сохранить уже готовый результат.

Comment: @Sergei22322 я хочу не открывая книги "Семеро смелых" прочитать её - примерно такой у Вас вопрос

Comment: Нет, я её открываю по сути на питоне с помощью wb=load_workbook("Имя файла"), и передаю в переменную могу при этом неоткрывая сам эксель вбить данные в нужные мне яйчейки и вывести, но вот проблема с формулами, openpyxl не может их посчитать не открывая(

Comment: Эксель в каждой ячейке при закрытом состоянии хранит и значения, и формулу. Если не нравится значение ячейки, то читайте из неё формулу, но что Вы с ней будете делать? Возможно, у Вас в настройках экселя настроено неавтоматический расчёт формул, хотя это слишком вряд ли.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, код позволяет открыть эксель файл и сохранить его, при этом автоматически посчитаются формулы с новыми значениями (если таковые были).
Данный кусок кода нужно вставить после того как мы добавили новые значения в эксель по которым посчитается формула в яйчейках которые мы можем изъять впоследствии.

```
import xlwings
from openpyxl import load_workbook

excel_app = xlwings.App(visible=False)
excel_book = excel_app.books.open('Лист1.xlsx')
excel_book.save()
excel_book.close()
excel_app.quit()
```